# Favorite Zombie Sounds?

Tags: sound-design, zombies, movies, video-games

There are a ton of zombie movies and video games out there.  Lots of different types of zombies too.  Ones that can almost talk, some are silent, some sound like animals, some just gurgle.  Do you have any particular movie or game that you like the sound design of the zombies in?

Answer (score 4):

I'm partial to Night of the Living Dead for nostalgia (first zombie flick I ever saw), Left 4 Dead for the variety, and Zombieland for those tiny little gurgly-bestial sounds of confusion - the undead version of a dog cocking its head and going, "barroo?" - that usually are in a beat of quiet before something, ahem, *untowards* befalls them.

There are many other faves, but for non-aural reasons (design, storytelling, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

The game "Plants vs. Zombies" had some nice old school zombie sounds.

I always love the meaty squash sound they make while walking, with all due respect to MJ's Thriller.

(I thought we shouldn't have a zombie sounds discussion without mentioning Thriller. After all they are the best sounding zombies ever, eh?) :)

Answer (score 3):

Return of the Living Dead ("BRAINS!") and the remake of Dawn of the Dead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if they're necessarily zombies but the creatures from I am Legend sounded great to me. Though anytime Mike Patton is utilized for vocals I'm down...  **[Patton explaining what he did for the film](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsK0GKajlsI)**

Comment: You can thank Jeremy Pierson for his creative efforts on that one: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0670586/

Answer (score 2):

Just watched Dead Snow - A Norwegian Zombie flick - great Zombie sounds, kind-of talkative and inquisitive - pretty funny some times.
Dawn of the Dead (Zach Snider) does the Zombie flick great justice and I liked the gargle adn growl of the zombies there.
Not so much a fan of the "28 days later" type roar in zombies.

Answer (score 1):

There does indeed seem to be two camps when it comes to the living dead - the "28 Days Later" vibe which seems much more guttural/aggressive, and the B-movie-styled growly/laughable (which is usually the point, I think).

I've been watching AMC's "The Living Dead" and I found myself a little surprised that the sound choices have been more on the B-movie side - the pickaxe through the head sounds they use are over the top, the zombie bites and organ tears.  It seems the intention of the sounds are not really to make you squirm, but to pay homage to those older zombie flicks.

Additionally, those sounds seem to generally sit "on top" of the mix as opposed to being part of the scene.  Interesting choices.  I'm not sure that I would choose to treat the show the same way, but I love hearing soundtracks that push those kinds of boundaries.

Cheers!

Comment: We were *just* discussing this in our office yesterday, and how even non-sound folks were really noticing how over the top the gore effects were. "Jeez, it sounds like Nathan eating," I think was one comment I heard... :-) It really cuts to the essence of this discussion, here: http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/4863/sound-design-should-not-be-noticeable-what-do-you-think

Answer (score 0):

The sound in Shaun of the Dead is great. More whooshy noises than you can shake a dead hand at.

Answer (score -1):

With all honesty, the Call Of Duty Zombie mode had really great affects in it. By far there moans and screams are very scary, and the zombies have different environmental themes to them.
slow pitch echoes in space, screechers, napalms and gas zombies alike are great. Not my favorite game, BUT… they had great zombies. Classic feel to them besides their glowing eyes and super man jumping and teleporting. And also Resident Evil Movies, Alice's flash back when the apocalypse was one of my favorite parts, and also watching zombies riding jeeps and motorcycles shooting guns and mounted machine-guns. Dawn of the Dead was a VERY great classic zombie movie. Dead Space has the most Horror feel into it, very incredible graphics, not to mention that they had a mix of aliens WITH zombies. Who doesn't like aliens and zombies?…

But of all of the more I could think of ( which is VERY VERY much I would be talking about.)
Dawn of the dead, flat out… Is theeeee- best classic zombie movie (fallow up of Night of the Living Dead) of all time. Can't get anymore of a classic zombie-movie then that film.

Comment: You seem to be talking about your favorite zombie films and games by overall experience instead of the sound.  You started out pretty well, but then seem to have meandered a bit.  Could you please try editing your post to explain a bit more about what about the sounds in those films and movies particularly you thought was good and cut out the non-sound related parts unless they impacted how you think the sound fit.